# How to add a linked item to another page in WooCommerce My Account menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

I am trying to add a linked item to another page (My page of BuddyPress) in the menu of WooCommerce My account. Is it possible?

I saw this thread: [How to add external custom url to woocommerce endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366494/how-to-add-external-custom-url-to-woocommerce-endpoint)

However, my page on BuddyPress could not be used because it could not be written in ULR and could not be written in *(May be just my lack of knowledge)*:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_menu_item_to_tabbed_my_account' );
function add_menu_item_to_tabbed_my_account( $menu_links ){

    // we will hook "anyuniquetext123" later
    $new_item = array( 'anyuniquetext123' => __('Candidate Dashboard') );

    // or in case you need 2 links
    // $new_item = array( 'link1' => 'Link 1', 'link2' => 'Link 2' );

    // array_slice() is good when you want to add an element between the other ones
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) 
    + $new_item 
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );

    return $menu_links;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'custom_endpoint_url', 10, 4 );
function custom_endpoint_url( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ){

    if( $endpoint === 'anyuniquetext123' ) {

        // BuddyPress My page link → <?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>
        // I want to make a link of this
        // ok, here is the place for your custom URL, it could be external
        $url = **'http://alatta.org.ye/candidate-dashboard/';**

    }
    return $url;
}
```

Actually, in addition to the main problem, when I change the name, I am troubled with an error.

[Change]
'** Candidate Dashboard **'　->　 'aaa'

[Error message]
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_STRING)

Comment: LoaThe Aztec Thank you for your correction. And I should have been more careful. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it safely with the following:

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_menu_item_to_tabbed_my_account' );
function add_menu_item_to_tabbed_my_account( $menu_links ){
    $new_item = array( 'anyuniquetext123' => __('Candidate Dashboard') );

    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) 
    + $new_item 
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );
 
    return $menu_links;
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'custom_endpoint_url', 10, 4 );
function custom_endpoint_url( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ){
    if( $endpoint === 'anyuniquetext123' ) {
 
        // I only had to describe it normally
        $url =  bp_loggedin_user_domain();
    }
    
    return $url;
}
```